# String concatenation in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to pass a parameter to a stored procedure which contains dynamic SQL.

For example,

`DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @sql = 
'select '+ @columnnames + ' from tablename'

EXECUTE(@sql)`

But @columnnames is a string created at runtime, by concatenating 2 strings
like 
@columnnames = a + ' ' + b

However this does not seem to work. I think I need to escape the single quotes. I have tried passing
 a + \' \' + b , but that doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you sure you don't need commas between the column names, as in other SQL implementations?

Answer (score 6):

```
declare @columnnames nvarchar(1000)
set @columnnames = 'a' + ' + '' '' + ' + 'b'
```

produces

```
select a + ' ' + b from tablename
```

Use apostrophe twice when you need apostrophe in resulting varchar .

Comment: Sorry but this does not work in stored procedure. I cannot pass parameter @columnames=N'a' + ' + '' '' + ' + 'b'. I cannot pass a and b separately because I do not know how many parameters need to be passed untill runtime.

Comment: @gunnerz This shows how to construct @ columnnames parameter outside of stored procedure. Could you please show SP definition and how you prepare the call?

Comment: Sorry Nikola. I did not have time to investigate it further. For the timebeing, I am reading the SP in a datatable the old-fashioned way.

Comment: @gunnerz Thank you for response. Good luck next time you tackle this problem again.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma...

```
set @columnnames = a + ',' + b
```

Comment: No I do not need 2 columns. I need concatenation of 2 columns.

Comment: Ah, sorry, mis-understood the question... Nikola has the correct answer